# How to pad numbers in a dataframe to a fixed length with zeros and get the first two digits

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner with Python, and I've been trying to extract the two first numbers of a 5 digit french postcode in order to create a column with the french department (which is a two digit code).
For those who don't know, a french postcode always contains 5 digits.
Moreover, the nine first french departments also have 5 digits but they begins with a 0, for example : The city "Cannes" corresponds to the postocode 06150, and I want to extract the department which is the 06.

However, in my datasets, the postcode of those nine first departments are written with only 4 digits, so when i extract the two firt numbers i get the wrong postcode:

Back to my Cannes example, the postcode is written 6150 (instead of 06150), if I extract the two first digits, i will get 61 (and not the 06 wanted).

So, i decided to use the function str.zfill(5), however i don't understand why this doesn't works :

```
df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS']= df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].astype(str) #Convert into string
df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'] = df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].str.zfill(5) #Supposed to add 0 on 4 digit postal codes
df['Departement']=df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[0:2]) #Extract the two firt digits on a new column called "Departement".
```

The zfill function didn't detect the 4 digits postcode so it doesn't fill the postcode with 0.
I Think my problem is my the first line of code, it adds a decimal at the end of every postcode (so the zfill function never detects 4 digits because there are 5 with the decimal).

The original column :

```
    CODE_POSTAL_PERS
0   59170
1   33310
2   40250
3   65000
4   60480
5   42152
6   99000
7   99000
8   21190
9   38000
```

And when a do this, it adds a decimal (i don't know why) :

```
df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].astype(str)
0         59170.0
1         33310.0
2         40250.0
3         65000.0
4         60480.0
5         42152.0
6         99000.0
7         99000.0
8         21190.0
9         38000.0
```

If the astype(str) function wouldn't had added a decimal i think it would have worked.
Thanks to everyone who will try to solve my problem !

Comment: Your example dataframe doesn't contain your Cannes example. Also, can you tell us what the data type of that column is? `df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].dtype`. It looks from your example that it is an integer type, which shouldn't contain the trailing `.0` when you convert to a string

Comment: Please don't add commentary to the question. You can post a comment if you want instead. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: May try converting to integer first then string? df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].astype(int).astype(str)

Comment: `df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'].astype(str).str.zfill(5).str[0:2]`

Comment: Are you sure the dataset only contains the last 4 digits, or is the leading zero being stripped when you read it into the df? That is, how are you creating the df exactly? It would help if you provided a [mre] including that plus input data including Cannes and the associated output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the type for you is useful. Do you need a string or integer number? I'm quite sure that you've figured that, when you cast an integer type of a string like '06150', the zero will be removed because, it does not makes sense for an integer, right? So I think that'll need to represent that in a string.

Another thing here is to keep things simple. If you are going to use strings, then you can use the *interpolation* method to mix variable values with a string, for instance:

```py
df = {}
df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'] = '6150'

# so far so good, now we're going to interpolate the string
# adding a zero at the begining of the string, by using python's f-String:
df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'] = f"0{df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS']}"

df['Departement'] = df['CODE_POSTAL_PERS'][:2]
print(df['Departement'])

# prints: 06
```

You can check the example here:

https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user306_9ZOG8jtzKu_0.py

#### Other Resources:

- Python f-String *(how interpolation works)*

  https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python